# 1 % of (the) GDP - with or without the article?

Tags: word-usage, articles, numbers

What is the correct form? I have consistently encountered both forms. Definite article: required, optional or wrong?

Comment: 1% of GDP vs 1% of the GDP:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1%25+of+the+GDP%2C+1%25+of+GDP&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C1%20%25%20of%20the%20GDP%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C1%20%25%20of%20GDP%3B%2Cc0

Comment: On its own, I would use "1% of GDP" or "1% of US GDP" but in context "1% of the GDP of the United States"

Comment: I think GDP is one of those terms that have somehow, gradually lost its definite article. I wonder if perhaps abbreviations are more susceptible to this.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are used commonly; however, the pattern seems to be that if a proper name follows the term *GDP*, then the article *the* is attached to *GDP*

> 5% of the GDP of Australia

whereas if no proper name follows *GDP*, then the article is not attached.

> 5% of GDP is lost.

Comment: This isn't quite right: you'd say "5% of the GDP of the country", not "5% of GDP of the country".  If I had a concise way of fixing this, I would do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be slightly more common without the article, i.e. 1% of GDP (Gross Domestic Product).    We say, "Exports have fallen this year", "profits have risen", "taxes have remained stable", but this makes sense because these words are plural and we are talking in the general sense so no article is required.  "Product", being a singular noun, should in theory require an article.  I think this is probably a case of usage not obeying the rules of grammar.

If you look in the British National Corpus, you will find both forms:
http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/